# How to use inspector in cobalt?

Tags: inspector, cobalt

I  launch chrome with this url http://ip_adress_device_cobalt:9222,when I try to navigate in developer tools tabs , the console works fine but other tabs (like network, source) are always empty. so I'am unable to use breakpoints for example or monitiring the network.

is there any other configure to do?

Comment: This will only work on the latest version of Cobalt on the master branch (and eventually in Cobalt 20), is this the version you are using?

Comment: I  use 19.lts.5.205289 cobalt version

Comment: I can see such error in log:"Unknown command: Overlay.highlightNode"

Answer (score 0):

DevTools is only in available in the **20.lts.1+** and newer branches of Cobalt. Also, you need to build with V8 rather than MozJs for full support, otherwise only the Console and some some basic functionality of Elements will work. The [documentation](https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/refs/heads/master/src/cobalt/doc/web_debugging.md) has more information, including notes about these requirements.

Cobalt 19 and some other earlier versions of Cobalt had an integration of DevTools as a remnant from before Cobalt used V8 or even MozJs, but it's terribly broken.

---

Don't worry about all the `Command not implemented` lines that show up in the Cobalt log. The [DevTools frontend](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend) is the same as used in Chrome (with some things turned off that Cobalt's backend doesn't support). It tries to do a lot as if it's talking to Chrome, and some things just aren't implemented in Cobalt. That's harmless as the frontend gracefully degrades, but the backend does log those unsupported commands that it receives from the frontend.

If you see `Unknown command` in the log instead, then you're running Cobalt 19, where DevTools doesn't really work anyway.